# Python Selenium: click on <input type=file> elements

Tags: python, selenium

I am creating a selenium bot for automatical blasting. I would like to download all my .fasta files into BLAST system and get the result.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def main():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastp&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome')
    element_download_files = driver.find_element_by_name("QUERYFILE")
    element_download_files.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This bot gets a response from [this page](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastp&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome) where is element for downloading files from your own PC. So here it is the tag of needed element:

```
<input type="file" id="upl" name="QUERYFILE">
```

But I have such traceback:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Cannot click <input type=file> elements
```

Is there a way to click on browse button which is not a HTML button? Or do I need to write a new code and use ? I suspect I can write code which will get BLAST sequences from my files and put it into  but I would like to know more about Selenium.

Thanks you for help and attention!

I use this:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Python 3.8.5
- Selenium 3.141.0
- Mozilla Firefox 87.0 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to click the upload field you just need to `send_keys` of actual file path

```py
element_download_files = driver.find_element_by_name("QUERYFILE")
element_download_files.send_keys("full/path/to/file")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to click the button. You can just input your file paths. This should help you: https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastp&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome